# \\\ prints just one backslash?

Tags: c

In C, on mentioning three backslashes, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    printf(" \\\ ");
}
```

prints out just one backslash in the output. Why and how does this work?

Answer (score 5):

That sequence is:

- A space
- A double backslash, which encodes a single backslash in the runtime string
- A backslash followed by a space, which is not a standard escape sequence and should give you a diagnostic

The C11 draft says (in note 77):

> The semantics of these characters were discussed in 5.2.2. If any other 
>   character follows a backslash, the result is not a token and a diagnostic is 
>   required.

On [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) I got:

> ```
> <source>:8:14: warning: unknown escape sequence '\ ' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
> ```

So you seem to be using a non-conforming compiler, which chooses to implement undefined backslash sequences by just letting the character through.

Answer (score 1):

That is printing:

```
space
slash
escaped space
```

The 3rd slash is being interpreted as "slash space"

Answer (score 1):

**C11; 6.4.4.4 Character constants:**

> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable either by themselves or by the
>   escape sequences `\"` and `\?`, respectively, but **the single-quote `'` and the backslash `\`
>   shall be represented, respectively, by the escape sequences `\'` and `\\`**.

So,  To represent a single backslash, it’s necessary to place double backslashes `\\` in the source code. To print two `\\` you need four backslash `\\\\`. In your code extra `\` is a space character, which isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a very simple operation in `c`. A `\` is just a escape sequences. Hence below statement will print two slash.

```
  printf(" \\\\ ");
```

For example some characters in `c` are represented with a slash like end of a line character `\n` or end of a string character `\0` etc. But if you want to print such a character as it is what will you do? Hence you need to add a escape sequence character in front of it:

```
printf("\\n"); // will print \n
```

But

```
printf("\n"); // will print end of character hence you don't see anything in output
```